# ARM Template deploymentScript PowerShell try catch ignored?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-rm-template

I am using an ARM Template of type "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts". That uses a PowerShell script that should add an identity to a role in Azure AD. When I run that a second time the post requests, the last Invoke-RestMethod, to add the member fails. That intentional and okay because the member is already there. I wrapped that in a try catch and look for the specific error. This works fine locally but not when deployed on Azure. It still stops at the line of the invoke, 41, and does not seem to respect the try catch around that. What am I doing wrong?

```
param([string] $spObjectId, $roleName, $tenantId, $clientId, $clientSecret)
Write-Host $ErrorActionPreference

$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
$Body = @{
    'tenant' = $tenantId
    'client_id' = $clientId
    'scope' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    'client_secret' = $clientSecret
    'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
}

$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
Write-Host $url

$Params = @{
    'Uri' = $url
    'Method' = 'Post'
    'Body' = $Body
    'ContentType' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

$AuthResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

$Headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($AuthResponse.access_token)"
}

$roles = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles' -Headers $Headers

$role = $roles.value | Where-Object { $_.displayName -eq "$roleName" }
$roleId = $role.id

$Body = @{
    "@odata.id"= "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/$spObjectId"
  }
$json = $Body | ConvertTo-Json
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/$roleId/members/`$ref"

try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Body $json -Headers $Headers -ContentType 'application/json' 
}
catch {
    $errordetails = $_.ErrorDetails.Message | ConvertFrom-Json
    if($errordetails.error.message -ne "One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'members'.")
    {
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Write-Host "Done"
```

The error in the Azure Portal

> The provided script failed with the following error:
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException: Response status
> code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at
> System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord
> errorRecord)  at ,
> /mnt/azscripts/azscriptinput/AddMemberToRole.ps1: line 41  at
> , : line 1  at ,
> /mnt/azscripts/azscriptinput/DeploymentScript.ps1: line 192. Please
> refer to https://aka.ms/DeploymentScriptsTroubleshoot for more
> deployment script information. (Code: DeploymentScriptError)

Comment: try adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to the cmdlet at like 41

Comment: btw, any reason you are using irm instead of Azure AD modules? are you 100% sure that line 41 on your local equals line 41 in the deploymentScript during execution?

Comment: Bug turned out to be something else and I didn't need the --ErrorAction Stop after all. I was passing in a string argument with space in a wrong way. That caused the exact same line to throw for a different reason and therefor being re-thrown. Thanks!

Comment: This runs on Linux and the AzureAD module, even the preview one, do not contain both the function to get the role as wel as the function to add a member to it.

Comment: why run this on linux?

Comment: Because I run this from an ARM Template using what is called a 'deploymentScripts'. That spins up a docker container on Azure Container Instances an runs the script in a Linux image

Comment: thanks captain! i'm looking at the api and it appears there is no way of setting the base container, which is weird. i had the impression its possible, but alas.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, `Invoke-RestMethod`'s error is captured in the try catch block. Your code looks correct and similar to what has to be done:

```
try{ $restp=Invoke-RestMethod (...) } catch {$err=$_.Exception}
$err | Get-Member -MemberType Property

  TypeName: System.Net.WebException

    Name           MemberType Definition
    ----           ---------- ----------
    Message        Property   string Message {get;}
    Response       Property   System.Net.WebResponse Response {get;}
    Status         Property   System.Net.WebExceptionStatus Status {get;}
```

*I suspect two reasons for this behavior:*

- [The ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template#configure-the-minimum-permissions) is having issues such that try catch block is neglected. Make sure the syntax is correct and expected (ARM works in local).
- An old deployed script is messing with this script. Try changing the resource name and redeploy.

Comment: Bug turned out to be something else. I was passing in a string argument with space in a wrong way from ARM into the PowerShell script. That caused the exact same line to throw for a different reason and therefor being re-thrown.

Comment: But why is it not catched?